# DEVISE extra field not getting saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add an extra field on my devise form like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="user_field">
    <div class="email">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
  </div>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email"%>
  </div>

  <div class="pass_field">
    <div class="password_field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em class = "minimum">(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br />
    </div>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="confirmation_field" input type = "hidden">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" id="public_key" name="public_key" value="" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("public_key").value = getkey();
    </script>
```

I have to permit the extra field so I create a new initializer devise_permitted_parameters.rb like this

```
module DevisePermittedParameters
extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters
end

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
end

end

DeviseController.send :include, DevisePermittedParameters
```

The output is this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8kB8VeA7pvoK0ROvfwwvibyyBUY/FOEHHYDYJbaBVz7+D2O3HrTYQihU1u8ePYC7nxH8qI2bJpWBjX2NZE0XIA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"wtgwg@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "public_key"=>"qEqGEPmShqM27Gc9CtYPfliPCRI7TQG3xTLZtl3ccIqQJwrvWS6jjZxkiJoM8fD/F4fL2y5xLH5S0Ye5LUiQJQ3SXqrGq1wbRwzEX1Y3GvV1dnNfwBcWvDkigQPvX11MUbzjf3Xiqf+1AtIaWY2+AB04Xou79BEgOtSSc8GDob0=", "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

(0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "wtgwg@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "hey"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$ew.ubHvxuvMrTHsuUqA8xu7ND7Xj3oGtNNR9YkziamJwPldsqvx22"], ["created_at", "2018-04-10 17:17:07.819645"], ["updated_at", "2018-04-10 17:17:07.819645"]]

The problem is that the public_key is getting stored. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in form

```
<%= f.text_field :public_key,id: "public_key" ,class: "hidden", value: "" %>
```

instead of

```
<input type="hidden" id="public_key" name="public_key" value="" />
```

Comment: I already made public_key a column in table. The value value of public_key is NULL on the table however

Comment: Kindly edit question & add code of UsersController & clear this getkey() method

Comment: Maybe you mean application_controller? I can't find any UsersController